# verifying the order of multiple methods call using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class Person that has two values, age and name, I'm doing some tests using Mockito for learning purpose.

My test method looks like:

```
        @Test()
        public void testFive(){
            Person mockedPerson = Mockito.mock(Person.class);
            Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getAge()).thenReturn(1,2,3);
            Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getName()).thenReturn("1","2","3");

            InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mockedPerson);

            mockedPerson.getAge();
            mockedPerson.getAge();
            mockedPerson.getAge();

            mockedPerson.getName();
            mockedPerson.getName();
            mockedPerson.getName();

            inOrder.verify(mockedPerson).getAge();
            inOrder.verify(mockedPerson).getAge();
            inOrder.verify(mockedPerson).getAge();
            inOrder.verify(mockedPerson).getName();
            inOrder.verify(mockedPerson).getName();
            inOrder.verify(mockedPerson).getName();
        }
```

I need to test that the getAge() method was called three times, and followed by three call to the getName() method.

I'm getting this exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.verification.VerificationInOrderFailure: 
>   Verification in order failure: person.getAge(); Wanted 1 time:

Comment: And what's the problem with your code?

Comment: just a BTW, you only added the first part of the error message, if you look at all of it it explicitly says that you wanted 1 time but it was called 3 times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your verifications should be like this:

```
        inOrder.verify(mockedPerson, times(3)).getAge();
        inOrder.verify(mockedPerson, times(3)).getName();
```

If you had more calls in the test, it should be this way:

```
    @Test
    public void testFive(){
        Person mockedPerson = Mockito.mock(Person.class);
        Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getAge()).thenReturn(1,2,3,4);
        Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getName()).thenReturn("1","2","3");

        InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mockedPerson);

        mockedPerson.getAge();
        mockedPerson.getAge();
        mockedPerson.getAge();

        mockedPerson.getName();
        mockedPerson.getName();
        mockedPerson.getName();

        mockedPerson.getAge();


        inOrder.verify(mockedPerson, times(3)).getAge();
        inOrder.verify(mockedPerson, times(3)).getName();
        inOrder.verify(mockedPerson, times(1)).getAge();
    }
```

What happens is that calling verify with no second argument verifies 1 call only (as if you wrote `times(1)`), and since you called 3 times it fails.

This is why I like to always add the `times(x)`, it makes things explicit.